# What does the eyeball button in the options tab do?

Tags: android, jetpack-joyride

When you open the settings in Jetpack Joyride on an Android device, you see an eyeball icon next to the Facebook icon. What does it do? Also, is it possible to restore your progress once you've reset your device?

[image]

Comment: This seems like two completely unrelated questions...

Comment: I disagree. They are both about the Android version of Jetpack Joyride.

Comment: On my iphone there is no eyeball icon, it's a cloud icon. hm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes the look of the game by adding effects like floor lights and turning coins. The game will reload if you press it.

Answer (score 1):

It changes the game between high-resolution and low-resolution graphics.